# How do the car packs work in Forza Horizon 2?

Tags: forza-horizon-2

In the Marketplace for Forza Horizon 2, you can purchase several car packs.   With the game I purchased, I also received a bunch of different car packs.  It shows that they are purchased and installed onto my Xbox One, but how can I access those cars?   They currently aren't in my garage... Do I have to then purchase those cars with CR to access them?

Comment: I don't have this game (stupid release date differences), but in FM5 you had to go to the store to get the cars  included in DLC into your garage, but they don't cost in-game currency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike Forza Motorsport 5, You still need to purchase the cars in the carpack with CR (First time is usually free). The Day 1 carpack for example are all cars already purchasable as you play through (for the same price as their boring counterparts), but they have a unique livery on them. Purchased Carpacks may be different. I haven't spent enough time in the carshow to be sure ;)

**EDIT**: It seems there was [server issues](http://forums.forzamotorsport.net/turn10_postst22765_Forza-Horizon-2-VIP-and-Server-Issues--Update--2--9-30-11-25-p-m--PST.aspx) at launch and car rewards may not have been given out.

```
Once the servers are stabilized, we will then get to sending out payouts for 
loyalty rewards cars, Forza Rewards payouts, etc.
```

Comment: Ah thank you for that link: "VIP Car Pack cars cost zero credits on first purchase, etc."  So it looks like you have to purchase them in game after you Buy them from the marketplace.

Comment: I don't think this is "unlike Forza Motorsport 5", I distinctly remember that I had the exact same options in that game, I could buy cars for 0 credits, once, after "getting them" through a purchased DLC. Of course, this might vary from DLC to DLC so perhaps others behaved like described though.

Answer (score 0):

I would figure you would have to go to pack or where you bought cars and they should be free without you spending anything

Comment: This soulds like a lot of guess works. Is this how DLC cars usualy work in this game?

Comment: I did go there, it shows purchased - but they are not located in my garage.